Certificate Installation Dialog Appears Behind .NET Application Window
I recently inherited a solution that wraps an application for Windows. I've been dealing with an issue for weeks and need some assistance.
When the application is run for the first time, a root certificate needs to be installed. However, the installation dialog appears behind the application. The installation of the root certificate is triggered through Titanium.Web.Proxy library, which includes functionality to ensure the certificate is correctly installed and trusted. Here is what the dialog looks like.
The solution is a WPF application targeting net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0.
I've tried setting Topmost = true for the application window, and while this solves the issue by bringing the dialog to the front, I do not want the application to remain in this state, as it prevents users from using Alt + Tab and other similar functions.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or has any ideas on how I could address this problem? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

There's a lot of missing details here. Please read [ask] and [edit] your post with a [mre]. Some useful points are, but are not limited to: What does the "installation dialog" look like and what code do you use to make it show up? "I tried setting Topmost = true" what type of application are we talking about, WinForms, WPF, MAUI, something else? "a .NET solution" what version of .NET are you targeting?

Thank you for the feedback and suggestions. This is my first post here, so I appreciate your patience. I've edited the post to include more details.
